# What is the optimal VBA method to convert 1D array into dynamic-dimension array?

Tags: excel, vba, transpose

A public database I use allows a user to select up to 20 unique variables and up to 10 years worth of data for each variable. The database then outputs that data into an Excel spreadsheet (beginning in Range A1) that is two rows tall and "n" columns long.

The first row of data is simply column headers, while the second row contains the actual data I want to use. The range A1:B2 is data that identifies the organization that the data relates to. So, the relevant data is in range C2:Cn. Finally, the data is organized reverse chronologically. So, if we were to pull two variables for the last two years the data, beginning in C2, would read:

Variable 1 (2019) | Variable 2 (2019) | Variable 1 (2018) | Variable 2 (2018)

My goal is to create a macro that will read this 1D array of data into memory, and then output that data into a multi-dimensional array in the following format :

Var1 | 2018 data | 2019 data

Var 2 | 2018 data| 2019 data

It seems to me the best option would be to use a for loop. I can determine the number of rows necessary for my output by prompting the user (me) to enter the number of variables I chose; the number of columns can be determined by entering the range.

As an Excel/VBA novice, I am not sure how to actually code this. What would be the optimal way of doing so?

Comment: There is some exclent info about arrays on [Chip's Website](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/Topic.aspx) - under 'A' there are a bunch of topics about arrays - some reading involved but well worth it!

Comment: Thank you, I will give this a read!